# Use ValueA when JOIN returns a row, otherwise ValueB (like a default)

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case, sql-null

I have four tables for a form-builder in my databse.

- `fields` (`fieldID(PK)`, `typeID`, `fieldName`, ...) - This table is a row by row list of all fields to be in the form
- `fields_types` (`typeID(PK)`, `htmlType`, ...) - This is a table that links fields to html types (and other settings)
- `fields_meta` (`FieldMetaID(PK)`, `FieldID`, `mName`, `mValue`) - Additional settings for fields, but more specific. A textarea field might have a height attribute, but almost no other field would use that.
- `fields_tyeps_meta` (`TypeMetaID(PK)`, `typeID`, `tmName`, `tmValue`) - Defines what extraneous settings a field can have, and also supplies default values if it's not explicitly set)

So my Query currently looks something like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Fields F
  JOIN Field_Types FT 
    on FT.FieldID = F.FieldID
  LEFT 
  JOIN Field_Meta FM 
    on FM.FieldID = F.FieldID
```

I was wondering if there's a way to join `Fields_Types_Meta` so that when the row's `JOIN` to `Fields_Meta` doesn't return a row (no `mValue`), it returns `tmValue`

I realize I can use something like `(CASE WHEN mValue = "" THEN tmValue ELSE mValue END) AS UseValue`, but I might have fields where I want to allow the value to be set to empty.

---

Edit: I could probably do something with a subquery and `COUNT`, using a `CASE` decision based on that. It might not be the healthiest performance-wise, but this query runs and caches itself til server restart, or until it's told to run again (updates to form design)

Comment: The right thing to do is `(CASE WHEN mValue IS NULL`, which is not the same as `= ""` (empty string). With that approach you will get `tmValue`  if you have no rows in `Field_Meta` ,but you if there are rows with empty `mValue` you'll get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want `¢oalesce()`:

```
coalesce(FM.mValue, FT.tmValue) as UseValue
```

When `FM.mValue` is `null`, `coalesce()` returns `FT.tmValue` instead.

If you have `null` values in `FM` that you want to preserve in the result set, then use a `case` expression instead:

```
case when FM.FieldID IS NULL THEN FT.tmValue ELSE FM.mValue END as UseValue
```

This phrases as: when the `left join` did find a match in `FM`, use `mValue` from that row (even if it is `null`), else use `FT.tmValue`.